# How to set Continuous WebJob as Singleton?

Tags: azure-webjobs

I've seen some guidance around using `settings.job` to set the WebJob as singleton but it's not working - in the console, I see:

```
 WebJob singleton setting is False
```

How can I go about preventing scale-outs from running multiple instances of my WebJob?

Comment: Which console are you talking about?

Comment: @Thomas the Azure Webjob dashboard console output

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As far as I know, to [set a continuous job as singleton](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/waws/2014/05/19/how-to-run-a-continuous-webjob-as-a-singleton/), we could create a file called `settings.job` with the content: `{ "is_singleton": true }` and put it at the root of the WebJob directory.
And we could [get continuous job settings](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/WebJobs-API) to make sure whether it is singleton.

```
GET /api/continuouswebjobs/{job name}/settings
```

[image]

> in the console I see:
> WebJob singleton setting is False

Please use Kudu tool to check whether the settings.job is existing at the root of the WebJob directory and the actual value of `is_singleton` property.

Answer (score 3):

If you can use the WebJobs SDK, I prefer to use the `Singleton` attribute.

[How to use the Azure WebJobs SDK for event-driven background processing - Singleton attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/webjobs-sdk-how-to#singleton-attribute)

```cs
[Singleton]
public static async Task ProcessImage([BlobTrigger("images")] Stream image)
{
     // Process the image.
}
```

If you have something like a ServiceBus trigger you should use `[Singleton(Mode = SingletonMode.Listener)]` in combination with the other host settings.